# scrapy export into single row

Tags: csv, parsing, scrapy, row

I'm trying to scrape store locations into a csv using scrapy. I'm capturing the right data, but the output looks like this (with "name" field as an example)

[csv output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wy7QH.png)

Code:

```
import scrapy

from xx.items import xxItem

class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'xx_spider'
    allowed_domains = ['www.my.xx.com']
    start_urls = [
                'https://my.xx.com/storefinder/list/a',
                ]

    def parse(self, response):  
        rows = response.css('div.col-md-4.col-sm-6')
        for row in rows:
            item = xxItem()  
            item['name'] = rows.css('h3::text').extract()
            item['address'] = rows.css('p::text').extract() 

        return item
```

Comment: Inside the loop: `rows` → `row`

Answer (score 0):

> A return statement is used to end the execution of the function call
> and “returns” the result (value of the expression following the return
> keyword) to the caller.

Reference [link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-return-statement/).

Hence, when you use `return` keyword, your code execution stops. Instead, you need to use `yield` keyword.

[What does the “yield” keyword do?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/231855)

### **Solution:**

Replace statement `return item` with `yield item` and move it to the `for loop` scope:

Code with changes:

```
import scrapy

from xx.items import xxItem

class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'xx_spider'
    allowed_domains = ['www.my.xx.com']
    start_urls = [
                'https://my.xx.com/storefinder/list/a',
                ]

    def parse(self, response):  
        rows = response.css('div.col-md-4.col-sm-6')
        for row in rows:
            item = xxItem()  
            item['name'] = row.css('h3::text').extract()
            item['address'] = row.css('p::text').extract() 

            yield item
```

To store data in csv file, run your spider using command:

```
scrapy crawl xx_spider -o output_file.csv
```

Hope it helps :)